# Name resolution for recursive trailing return type

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I found a weird difference between explicit and automatic trailing return types.

In the following code, we define a struct templated on an integer and an iter function, which take one object of this type as argument. The return type depends on the result of calling itself after decrementing the template value.

To break the instantiation loop (or so I thought), I provide a specialization which returns a non-dependent type.

We have a toy main to instantiate the templates.

Here is a bit of code:

```
template<int i> struct Int {};

constexpr auto iter(Int<0>) -> Int<0>;

template<int i> constexpr auto iter(Int<i>) -> decltype(iter(Int<i-1>{}));

int main(){
  decltype(iter(Int<10>{})) a;
}
```

This code does not work in both gcc 4.9 and clang 3.5. Both trigger infinite instantiation (they don't match the specialized base case).

```
rec.cpp:11:62: fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 256
template<int i> constexpr auto iter(Int<i>) -> decltype(iter(Int<i-1>{}));
```

Now, if we use C++14 `decltype(auto)` and we provide a body for the template which returns the exact same thing:

```
template<int i> struct Int {};

constexpr auto iter(Int<0>) -> Int<0>;

template<int i>
constexpr auto iter(Int<i>) -> decltype(auto) {
  return iter(Int<i-1>{});
}

int main(){
  decltype(iter(Int<10>{})) a;
}
```

This now works for both compilers and behave as expected.

I tried different ways to express the specialization and moved it around a bit (to be careful about its location), but that didn't prevent its self-immolation ;(

I also tried to sprinkle the code with more `decltype` and `declval`, but I can't seem to get the C++11 syntax working.

Could someone explain the difference between the two syntaxes for the name lookup?

Comment: `decltype(auto)` doesn't do SFINAE, and doesn't need to do name resolution. It's not just a "more compact" version of the former. Btw, a trick is to stuff the whole thing into a class.

Comment: SFINAE is not involved here. The compiler does have to compute the result type of the recursive call to find the return type of iter in both cases, I don't understand why the non-auto fails to match the specialization. A struct here wouldn't help: this code is not particularly useful, it's just the shortest example I came up with.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's because of the relative ordering of overload resolution, template overload resolution, template declaration instantiation, and template *definition* instantiation.

Let's look at the C++11 case first.  When the compiler needs to evaluate `decltype(iter(Int<0>{}))`, it performs overload resolution on the name `iter` called with arguments prvalue `Int<0>`. Since a template is in the overload set, we apply 14.8.3 **[temp.over]**:

> 1 - A function template can be overloaded either by (non-template) functions of its name or by (other) function templates of the same name. When a call to that name is written (explicitly, or implicitly using the operator notation), template argument deduction (14.8.2) and checking of any explicit template arguments (14.3) are performed for each function template to find the template argument values (if any) that can be used with
>   that function template to instantiate a function template specialization that can be invoked with the call arguments. [...]

As a result, the declaration `template<int i> constexpr auto iter(...) -> ...` is instantiated (14.7.1p10 **[temp.inst]**) with `i = 0`, which forces the evaluation of `decltype(iter(Int<-1>{}))` and off down the rabbit hole of negative integers we go.

It doesn't matter that `constexpr auto iter(Int<0>) -> Int<0>` would be a better overload (by 13.3.3p1 **[over.match.best]**), because we never get that far; the compiler is away marching merrily towards negative infinity.

By contrast, with C++14 deduced return types 7.1.6.4p12 **[dcl.spec.auto]** applies:

> 12 - Return type deduction for a function template with a placeholder in its declared type occurs when the definition is instantiated [...]

Since definition instantiation occurs *after* template overload resolution (14.7.1p3), the bad template `iter<0>` is never instantiated; 14.8.3p5:

> 5 - Only the signature of a function template specialization is needed to enter the specialization in a set of candidate functions. Therefore only the function template declaration is needed to resolve a call for which a template specialization is a candidate.

The "signature" of `iter<0>` here is `(Int<0>) -> decltype(auto)`, a signature containing a *placeholder type* (7.1.6.4).

---

Suggested workaround: use SFINAE to prevent any attempted call to `iter(Int<-1>{})`:

```
template<int i> constexpr auto iter(Int<i>)
  -> decltype(iter(typename std::enable_if<i != 0, Int<i-1>>::type{}));
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^
```

Note that the SFINAE has to go *inside* the `decltype`, and indeed inside the call to `iter`.

Comment: Then why does `template<int i> auto iter(Int<i>) -> decltype(iter(Int<(i==0?0:i-1)>()));` not work?

Comment: @Adrian same reason; here instantiation of the declaration of `iter<0>` forces instantiation of the same declaration of `iter<0>`, and so on; the compiler error message should tell you this.  There are no rules for breaking cycles in template overload resolution, other than the usual depth limit.

Comment: So it doesn't matter that _the compiler is away marching merrily towards negative infinity_ then?  It is just trying to redeclare the same function over and over again?

Comment: @Adrian OP's case: instantiating the declaration of `iter<0>` requires instantiating the declaration of `iter<-1>` requires instantiating the declaration of `iter<-2>` and so forth.  Your case: instantiating the declaration of `iter<0>` requires instantiating the declaration of `iter<0>` requires instantiating the declaration of `iter<0>` and so forth.  Both infinite loops, only the scenery is different.

Comment: Yes, I'm just trying to clarify that the requirement of _instantiating the declaration of `iter<0>`_ doesn't have to do with the template parameter decrementing, but has to do with the template function declaration never being instantiated.  Is that right?

Comment: @Adrian yes, the template function declaration can't be instantiated because it causes unterminated recursion.

Comment: @Adrian Note that in this context, your alternative declaration says "the return type of `iter<0>` is the return type of `iter<0>` (is what `iter<0>` returns)" -- and that's not a meaningful definition of a return type, even if the recursion would not be performed.

Comment: @ecatmur Excellent answer, thanks. I tried to find clues in the standard myself but didn't manage to piece everything together. Out of curiosity, do c++14 deduced return types (without `decltype`) behave like `decltype(auto)`?

Comment: @Thibaut yes, as long as you specify `decltype(auto)` as the placeholder type. `auto f() { return ... }` will use `auto` rules; `decltype(auto) g()` will use `decltype(auto)`, and if you put a placeholder in a trailing-return-type (after `->`) then that overrides the initial placeholder.

Comment: I dont understand how `14.8.3` applies here. It is not clear as to why the overload with `Int<0>` isn't selected. Is that not visible there?

Comment: @Nawaz it is indeed visible, but the compiler has to instantiate the recursive case `template<int i> constexpr auto iter(Int<i>) -> decltype(iter(Int<i-1>{}));` with `[i = 0]` anyway, to check whether it is a viable overload.

Comment: Is `auto iter() -> decltype(auto)` any different here than plain `auto iter()`? There's no referenceness that you want to keep, right? I'm asking because of a recent comment on [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109737/what-are-some-uses-of-decltypeauto/24109800?noredirect=1#comment83639641_24109800)

Comment: Why did not compiler stop with `i == 1`? Wasn't it suppose to deduce `decltype(iter(Int<0>{}))` as `Int<0>` (based on overload provided) and stop the recursion there? Why did not it use the right overload at that step?

Comment: @Dmitry the compiler doesn't know that `constexpr auto iter(Int<0>) -> Int<0>;` is the best overload for `i == 0`; it has to instantiate the other overload as well to check whether it is better.

Comment: @ecatmur Yeah I think I got it, but I was playing around with this code and still have couple of questions. For instance, if we replace `int` (non-type template argument) with `uint8_t` making the set of possible values small enough (256 in total) as well as allow integer overflow (0 - 1 == 255 now) everything works (or at least compiles). Is that standard behavior or sort of IFNDR. Cause I can not really understand how compiler is able to break the recursion in that case.

Comment: @Dmitry for `uint8_t`, how it works is that when trying to deduce the return type for the template overload on `i == 0u` the compiler will, as you've observed, overflow to 255u and back down to 0; when it gets to 0 it will observe that it is *currently* deducing the return type for the template overload for `i == 0u` and so fail deduction for that overload (as SFINAE) leaving only the non-template overload.