# What is difference between decltype(auto) and decltype(returning expr) as return type?

Tags: c++, c++14, auto, decltype

What is the difference between `decltype(auto)` and `decltype(returning expression)` as return type of a function (template) if `expr` used without parentheses in both cases?

```
auto f() -> decltype(auto) { return expr; } // 1
auto f() -> decltype(expr) { return expr; } // 2
```

Above `f` can be defined/declared in any context and can be either (member) function or (member) function template, or even (generic) lambda. `expr` can depend on any template parameters.

In second version both `expr` are exactly the same expression without extra parentheses.

Which differences can one expect, using first or second form in C++14 and later?

What if parentheses used everywhere?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes there is a difference. The first one will detect the return type based on the return expression in the body of the function.

The second one will not also set the return type to the type of the expression inside `decltype()`, but will also apply *expression sfinae* on it. That means that if the expression inside decltype is not valid, the compiler will search for another valid overload. Whereas the first version will be a hard error.

Take this example:

```
template<typename T>
auto fun(T a) -> decltype(a.f()) { return a.f(); }

template<typename T>
auto fun(T a) -> decltype(a.g()) { return a.g(); }

struct SomeType {
    int g() { return 0; }
};

fun(SomeType{});
```

This select the correct overload. Now if we replace `decltype(expr)` by `decltype(auto)`, the compiler will not be able to select the correct overload, as there's nothing *in the function signature* that constrains what the type is supposed to be able to do.

Answer (score 6):

`decltype(auto)` is used to

- Forward return type in generic code, you don't want to type a lot of duplicate thing

  ```
  template<class Func, class... Args>
  decltype(auto) foo(Func f, Args&&... args) 
  { 
      return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
  }
  ```
- Delay type deduction, as you can see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036357/name-resolution-for-recursive-trailing-return-type), compilers have some problem with out `decltype(auto)`

  - This doesn't work well as you can see with [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9904ccca5ebf0b5) and [clang++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16c5664820adcadf)

    ```
    template<int i> struct Int {};
    constexpr auto iter(Int<0>) -> Int<0>;

    template<int i> constexpr auto iter(Int<i>) -> decltype(iter(Int<i-1>{}));

    int main(){
      decltype(iter(Int<10>{})) a;
    }
    ```
  - This works well as you can see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83c58b9b096c8d4a):

    ```
    template<int i> struct Int {};

    constexpr auto iter(Int<0>) -> Int<0>;

    template<int i>
    constexpr auto iter(Int<i>) -> decltype(auto) {
      return iter(Int<i-1>{});
    }

    int main(){
      decltype(iter(Int<10>{})) a;
    }
    ```

`decltype(expr)`:

- applies SFINAE while `decltype(auto)` is not

Answer (score 3):

Yet another example. In the `decltype(auto)` case, lambdas are allowed. In the `decltype(expr)` case, lambdas are disallowed.

That's because a) lambdas are not allowed as unevaluated operands (such as in `sizeof` or `decltype`) and b) the type in the `decltype` and in the body of the two expressions would be different, since they are two distinct lambda expressions

```
// ill-formed: lambda within decltype
auto f() -> decltype([]{}) { return []{}; };

// allowed: lambda is not in decltype, and only appears once
auto f() -> decltype(auto) { return []{}; }
```

Comment: `auto f() -> decltype([]{}) { return {}; }` would work?

Comment: @Orient nopes, sorry

Comment: What do you think, is [this](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23141) problem somehow related to this question?

Comment: Lambdas will be allowed in C++20