# Perfect-forwarding a return value with auto&&

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, perfect-forwarding

Consider this quote from *C++ Templates: The Complete Guide (2nd Edition)*:

> ```
> decltype(auto) ret{std::invoke(std::forward<Callable>(op),
>                                std::forward<Args>(args)...)};
> ...
> return ret;
> ```
>
> Note that declaring `ret` with `auto&&` is not correct. As a
>   reference, `auto&&` extends the lifetime of the returned value until
>   the end of its scope **but not beyond the `return` statement to the
>   caller of the function**.

The author says that `auto&&` is not appropriate for perfect-forwarding a return value. However, doesn't `decltype(auto)` also form a reference to xvalue/lvalue?
IMO, `decltype(auto)` then suffers from the same issue. Then, what's the point of the author?

**EDIT:**

The above code snippet shall go inside this function template.

```
template<typename Callable, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) call(Callable&& op, Args&&... args) {
    // here
}
```

Comment: `int foo() { return 1; } /* ... */ auto &&ret = foo(); decltype(auto) ret2 = foo();` wouldn't act the same...

Comment: @W.F. Can you be more specific? I'm specifically concerning about the lifetime.

Comment: Depends on the function's declared return type. You'd better quote more so that we can understand the context.

Comment: A toy [\[example\]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/X3qtGHLrSBSZgedZ) of what author could have in mind... see the warning

Comment: @xskxzr the function's return type is also `decltype(auto)`.

Comment: You should edit the question to clarify it.

Comment: @xskxzr: It's not really relevant here, though good general advice to present a MCVE

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If the declared return type is `auto`, using `auto&& ret{...}` is acceptable. On the other hand, if the declared return type is `auto&&`, using `decltype(auto) ret{...}` still results in a lifetime problem.

Comment: @xskxzr: Yes but we can answer generally perfectly well, covering both cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two deductions here. One from the return expression, and one from the `std::invoke` expression. Because [`decltype(auto)` is deduced to be the declared type for unparenthesized id-expression](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#4.2), we can focus on the deduction from the `std::invoke` expression.

Quoted from [[dcl.type.auto.deduct] paragraph 5:](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.auto.deduct#5)

> If the placeholder is the `decltype(auto)` *type-specifier*, `T` shall be the placeholder alone. The type deduced for `T` is determined as described in [dcl.type.simple], as though `e` had been the operand of the `decltype`.

And quoted from [[dcl.type.simple] paragraph 4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#4):

> For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>
> - if `e` is an unparenthesized id-expression naming a structured binding ([dcl.struct.bind]), `decltype(e)` is the referenced type as given in the specification of the structured binding declaration;
> - otherwise, if `e` is an unparenthesized *id-expression* or an unparenthesized class member access, `decltype(e)` is the type of the entity named by `e`. If there is no such entity, or if `e` names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
> - otherwise, if `e` is an xvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
> - otherwise, if `e` is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
> - otherwise, `decltype(e)` is the type of `e`.

Note `decltype(e)` is deduced to be `T` instead of `T&&` if `e` is a prvalue. This is the difference from `auto&&`.

So if `std::invoke(std::forward<Callable>(op), std::forward<Args>(args)...)` is a prvalue, for example, the return type of `Callable` is not a reference, i.e. returning by value, `ret` is deduced to be the same type instead of a reference, which perfectly forwards the semantic of returning by value.

Comment: The whole problem certainly stems from my misunderstanding of `decltype(e)`! Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 6):

> However, doesn't decltype(auto) also form a reference to xvalue/lvalue?

No.

Part of `decltype(auto)`'s magic is that it knows `ret` is an lvalue, [so it will not form a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24109944/560648).

If you'd written `return (ret)`, it would indeed have resolved to a reference type and you'd be returning a reference to a local variable.

**tl;dr: `decltype(auto)` is not always the same as `auto&&`.**

Comment: Isn't `decltype(auto)` semantically same with `decltype(e)` for some expression `e`? The standard says, `otherwise, if e is an lvalue, decltype(e) is T&, where T is the type of e;`.

Comment: @b1sub you forgot [\[dcl.type.simple\]/4.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#4.2) which is relevant here

Comment: @W.F. This seems an answer.

Comment: Referring to `Isn't decltype(auto) semantically same with decltype(e) for some expression e` - [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946408/is-there-a-special-rule-for-lambda-in-case-of-decltypeauto)

Comment: @W.F. BTW, `decltype(auto)` is not applied to `ret`. The initializer is not `id-expression` so that it must form a reference for some cases (i.e., xvalue/lvalue).

Comment: I agree with all your conclusions, and that there will be no references formed when `e` is prvalue. I just wanted to point out that, the fact that the identifier `ret` is lvalue has nothing to do with the type deduction. But, if `ret` was an expression of `decltype(e)`, that would be an another story. Hope that I cleared out any misunderstanding.

Comment: True, that part is not strictly completely accurate.

Comment: Thank you for bearing with me. Have a nice day. =)

Answer (score 2):

`auto&&` is always a reference type. On the other hand, `decltype(auto)` can be either a reference or a value type, depending on the initialiser used.

Since `ret` in the `return` statement is not surrounded by parenthesis, `call()`'s deduced return type only depends on the *declared type* of the *entity* `ret`, and **not** on the *value category* of the *expression* `ret`:

```
template<typename Callable, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) call(Callable&& op, Args&&... args) {
   decltype(auto) ret{std::invoke(std::forward<Callable>(op),
                                  std::forward<Args>(args)...)};
   ...
   return ret;
}
```

If `Callable` returns *by value*, then the value category of `op`'s call expression will be a ***prvalue***. In that case:

- `decltype(auto)` will deduce `res` as a non-reference type (i.e., value type).
- `auto&&` would deduce `res` as a reference type.

As explained above, the `decltype(auto)` at `call()`'s return type simply results in the same type as `res`. Therefore, if `auto&&` would have been used for deducing the type of `res` instead of `decltype(auto)`, `call()`'s return type would have been a reference to the local object `ret`, which does not exist after `call()` returns.

Comment: "`auto&&` is always a reference type. " does this mean it can be either `T&` or `T&&`(and nothing else?)

Comment: @PYA it can also be decorated in different ways, e.g., `const T&`. The point is that it will never become a *value type*, always a reference.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question, but specific to how to properly return `ret` as if we called `invoke` directly instead of `call`.

In the example you show, `call(A, B)` **does not** have the same return type of `std::invoke(A, B)` for every `A` and `B`.

Specifically, when `invoke` returns an `T&&`, `call` returns a `T&`.

You can see it in this example ([wandbox link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/p3xQwdvkn2PdujJ1))

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct PlainReturn {
    template<class F, class Arg>
    decltype(auto) operator()(F&& f, Arg&& arg) {
        decltype(auto) ret = std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
        return ret;
    }
};

struct ForwardReturn {
    template<class F, class Arg>
    decltype(auto) operator()(F&& f, Arg&& arg) {
        decltype(auto) ret = std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
        return std::forward<decltype(ret)>(ret);
    }
};

struct IfConstexprReturn {
    template<class F, class Arg>
    decltype(auto) operator()(F&& f, Arg&& arg) {
        decltype(auto) ret = std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
        if constexpr(std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(ret)>) {
            return std::move(ret);
        } else {
            return ret;
        }
    }
};

template<class Impl>
void test_impl(Impl impl) {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, decltype(impl([](int) -> int {return 1;}, 1))>, "Should return int if F returns int");
    int i = 1;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int&, decltype(impl([](int& i) -> int& {return i;}, i))>, "Should return int& if F returns int&");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int&&, decltype(impl([](int&& i) -> int&& { return std::move(i);}, 1))>, "Should return int&& if F returns int&&");
}

int main() {
    test_impl(PlainReturn{}); // Third assert fails: returns int& instead
    test_impl(ForwardReturn{}); // First assert fails: returns int& instead
    test_impl(IfConstexprReturn{}); // Ok
}
```

So it appears that the only way to properly forward the return value of a function is by doing

```
decltype(auto) operator()(F&& f, Arg&& arg) {
    decltype(auto) ret = std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
    if constexpr(std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(ret)>) {
        return std::move(ret);
    } else {
        return ret;
    }
}
```

This is quite a pitfall (which I discovered by falling into it!).

Functions which return `T&&` are rare enough that this can easily go undetected for a while.