# Why does infinite recursion in template instantiation happen when using trailing return type with decltype that calls the function with same name?

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

Look at this code:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A(...) {}
};

template <typename T>
auto Func(A<T> &&a)
  -> void
{
}

template <typename T>
auto Func(A<T>  &a)
  -> decltype( Func<T>(std::move(a)) )
    { return ( Func<T>(std::move(a)) ); }

int main()
{
    Func<int>(5);
}
```

The second overload requests `decltype` that should return "return type" of the first overload (that is `void`).

But when I try to compile this code with *GCC*, it says that template instantiation depth exceeds maximum:

```
main.cpp: In substitution of 'template<class T> decltype (Func<T>(std::move(a))) Func(A<T>&) [with T = int]':
main.cpp:17:23:   recursively required by substitution of 'template<class T> decltype (Func<T>(std::move(a))) Func(A<T>&) [with T = int]'
main.cpp:17:23:   required by substitution of 'template<class T> decltype (Func<T>(std::move(a))) Func(A<T>&) [with T = int]'
main.cpp:22:14:   required from here
main.cpp:17:33: fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use '-ftemplate-depth=' to increase the maximum)
   17 |   -> decltype( Func<T>(std::move(a)) )
      |                        ~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

[coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1269dbb4e3e6a994)

When I try to compile this code with *CLang*, it just **crashes**:

```
#0 0x00007f0d4efc7eea llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-5.0.so.1+0x7fbeea)
#1 0x00007f0d4efc606e llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-5.0.so.1+0x7fa06e)
#2 0x00007f0d4efc61bc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-5.0.so.1+0x7fa1bc)
#3 0x00007f0d51d9d390 __restore_rt (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+0x11390)
#4 0x00007f0d4ef6311e llvm::FoldingSetNodeID::ComputeHash() const (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-5.0.so.1+0x79711e)
#5 0x00007f0d4ef6318a llvm::FoldingSetBase::FindNodeOrInsertPos(llvm::FoldingSetNodeID const&, void*&) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-5.0.so.1+0x79718a)
#6 0x0000000001838633 clang::ASTContext::getLValueReferenceType(clang::QualType, bool) const (/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/clang+0x1838633)
#7 0x00000000013dee9e (/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/clang+0x13dee9e)
#8 0x00000000013e0998 clang::Sema::DeduceTemplateArguments(clang::FunctionTemplateDecl*, clang::TemplateArgumentListInfo*, llvm::ArrayRef<clang::Expr*>, clang::FunctionDecl*&, clang::sema::TemplateDeductionInfo&, bool, llvm::function_ref<bool (llvm::ArrayRef<clang::QualType>)>) (/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/clang+0x13e0998)
#9 0x000000000131d398 clang::Sema::AddTemplateOverloadCandidate(clang::FunctionTemplateDecl*, clang::DeclAccessPair, clang::TemplateArgumentListInfo*, llvm::ArrayRef<clang::Expr*>, clang::OverloadCandidateSet&, bool, bool) (/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/clang+0x131d398)
#10 0x000000000131e0d5 (/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/clang+0x131e0d5)
#11 0x000000000131e22b clang::Sema::AddOverloadedCallCandidates(clang::UnresolvedLookupExpr*, llvm::ArrayRef<clang::Expr*>, clang::OverloadCandidateSet&, bool) (/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/clang+0x131e22b)
#12 0x000000000131e3da clang::Sema::buildOverloadedCallSet(clang::Scope*, clang::Expr*, clang::UnresolvedLookupExpr*, llvm::MutableArrayRef<clang::Expr*>, clang::SourceLocation, clang::OverloadCandidateSet*, clang::ActionResult<clang::Expr*, true>*) (/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/clang+0x131e3da)
#13 0x000000000132a6a3 clang::Sema::BuildOverloadedCallExpr(clang::Scope*, clang::Expr*, clang::UnresolvedLookupExpr*, clang::SourceLocation, llvm::MutableArrayRef<clang::Expr*>, clang::SourceLocation, clang::Expr*, bool, bool) (/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/clang+0x132a6a3)
#14 0x00000000011d1e04 clang::Sema::ActOnCallExpr(clang::Scope*, clang::Expr*, clang::SourceLocation, llvm::MutableArrayRef<clang::Expr*>, clang::SourceLocation, clang::Expr*, bool) (/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/clang+0x11d1e04)
#15 0x000000000140679c (/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/clang+0x140679c)
#16 0x00000000013f5b2e (/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/clang+0x13f5b2e)
#17 0x00000000013ff848 (/usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/clang+0x13ff848)
...
```

[coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29aeb6c0d9830346)

What's wrong with this code? How can I fix it?

**The story**

What I actually want is to make a function that has the same implementation for both `A<T> &&` and `A<T> &` parameters. I want to implement one overload, and in the second overload I just want to redirect the call to the first overload. If my code is not valid, how can I do this another way?

Comment: It's a bit unusual to have an rvalue overload and a non-const lvalue overload do the exact same thing. The lvalue overload modifies something you can inspect later, it's a change that persists. An rvalue reference is usually meant to bind to discardable things. Why would you want to allow changing it the same way? Seems like pointless work.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, it is kind of `Move` function, that moves content of `A<T>` to some class `B`. And I can't add constructor to the `B` class that takes rvalue reference of the `A` class. And I don't want to write `Move(std::move(a))`.

Comment: Why not? `std::move` on things we want to mark as discardable and eligible for cannibalizing is idiomatic C++. If you work with common idioms life is easier. Also, silently mutating lvalues can be a source of many evils...

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, IMO one `Move` is just enough.

Comment: Indeed. Maybe the bigger mistake is calling your operation `Move`.

Comment: The code would not compile because the constructor is private. I don't know why the compilers ignore it in main while calling `Func<int>(5)`.

Comment: @S.M., because it can't even instantiate the function. Instantiation happens before calling constructor. **PS** I made the constructor public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case is actually the **trailing return type which triggers the infinite recursion**

```
  -> decltype(Func<T>(std::move(a)))
```

You can read more about why this happens in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24043642/9938686).

If you are working with C++14 and later just leave it out and it should work: [Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iwZP9SIcB4B52mQA)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use C++14.

Answer (score 4):

You can add an optional template parameter to direct to the function that uses the rvalue reference as an overload to avoid the infinite recursion.

```cpp
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A(...) {}
};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto Func(A<T> &&a)
  -> void
{
}

template <typename T>
auto Func(A<T> &a)
  -> decltype( Func<T, void>(std::move(a)) )
    { return ( Func<T, void>(std::move(a)) ); }

int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    Func<int>(a);
    Func<int>(A<int>());
}
```

Also works with [C++11](https://godbolt.org/z/5nfETqEWY).

Comment: This is a possible solution for C++11 but your SFINAE does not ensure that there is no infinite recursion. As you can see [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1UOcrXhXp5Hvpslt) also works. Your function is simply calling a different overload that never has problems with recursion.

Comment: @2b-t Well, technically, the OP was trying to make both the overloads of `Func` do the same thing. `std::move(a)` has type `A<T>&&`, so the OP was intentionally trying to call the other overload without facing an infinite recursion. In that context, I think my answer is well-found. Also, I edited the answer a bit to make it clearer.

Comment: Yes, I agree. It is a good answer but you didn't need the SFINAE. Upvoted it!